# Mercurial Project import in eclipse using SSH key authentication

Tags: mercurial, eclipse-plugin, ssh-keys

I have the hgeclipse plugin installed and I have a url source to go and clone from for a project that I need to begin work on. The authentication is based on ssh and my ssh key. I understand from basic googling that I need to set up a .hgr file with the path to the private. Can some one give me more pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you can include the path to the key in your Mercurial.ini/.hrgc file.  You don't need Pageant or ssh-agent, unless you need to log in to multiple servers.  If you're only ever logging in to one server, you can make your Mercurial.ini or .hgrc file have the following content:

```
[ui]
ssh = "TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2 -i "C:\Users\username\username_rsa.ppk"
```

This code is Windows-specific but basically, you just specify the path to the ssh program, use the -i flag and specify the path to the private key.  That formula should work on all operating systems.  If you're on Windows, you put that stuff in a file called "Mercurial.ini" and if you're on any other platform, it goes in a file called .hgrc

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The private key must be added to ssh and not mercurial / hgrc.

You have to configure your ssh client to use your private key, but this depends greatly on the system you're using.

If you're on linux or mac os x, google some informations about using `ssh-agent` on your distribution.

If you're on Windows, you can use [pageant](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) for example.